# hue always numerical in seaborn FacetGrid with stripplot

Tags: python, seaborn, facet-grid

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I basically have the below situation and I want to have the color variable interpreted as categorical.
Different values of `'a'` should be easily recognizable by color.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    a=['a'] * 5 + ['b'] * 5,
    b=[1, 2, 3, 2, 1] * 2,
    c=['x', 'y'] * 5))
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, col='c', sharey=True)
g = g.map_dataframe(sns.stripplot, x='a', y='b', hue='a')
```

I tried defining `hue` in `FacetGrid` but then `'a'` is not mapped to the x axis anymore.

Comment: There are blue and black dots in the plot. In how far is this not what you want?

Comment: I think this is a numerical palette (from light blue to dark blue). If I create a sns.stripplot without FacetGrid I get colors blue and orange.

Comment: I see. Maybe it'd be helpful to show both codes with their respective output pictures in the question, so people can understand the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To easily distinguish the dots by color, you can set the color map explicitly with the `palette` parameter.

```
g = g.map_dataframe(sns.stripplot, x='a', y='b', hue='a', palette='tab10')
```

[image]